# Open one accordion section at a time. (Svelte)

Tags: javascript, html, accordion, svelte

I'd like to ask someone who can figure out how to allow this accordion component to open only one section at a time.

It means that if a new accordion is open the previous one has to close automatically.

In the ideal situation, this function could be optional for specific accordions.

Thank you for your time.

**Accordion.svelte**

```
 <script>
    import { linear } from 'svelte/easing';
    import { slide} from 'svelte/transition';
    
    export let open = false;

    function handleClick() {
        open = !open
    } 
    
</script>

   <div  class="accordion">
      <div class="header" on:click={handleClick}>
          <div class="text">
              <slot name="head"></slot> 
          </div>
      </div>

      {#if open}
      <div class="details" transition:slide="{{duration: 500, easing: linear}}" >
          <slot name="details">
          </slot>
      </div>
      {/if}

  </div>

<style>
       div.accordion {
          margin: 1rem 0;
      }
      
      div.header {
          display:flex;
          width:100%;
      }
      
      div.header .text {
          flex: 1;
      }
      
      div.details {
          background-color: transparent;
          padding:1rem;
      }
  </style>
```

**app.svelte**

```
<script>

import Accordion from "./Accordion.svelte"

</script>

       <Accordion>
          <div slot="head">
              <h2>Test one</h2>
          </div>
          <div slot="details">
              <ul>
                <Accordion>
                    <div slot="head">
                      <h4>The test of subitem?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div slot="details">
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                    </div>
                </Accordion >

                <Accordion>
                    <div slot="head">
                        <h4>Test of subitem 2</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div slot="details">
                        <li>one</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                        <li>three</li>
                    </div>
                </Accordion>
              </ul>
          </div>
       </Accordion>

       <Accordion>
          <div slot="head">
              <h4>Second test</h4>
          </div>
          <div slot="details">
              <ul>
                  <li>again one</li>
                  <li>two again</li>
                  <li>three repeat</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </Accordion>


<style>
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

h4, h2 {
        cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: It's not that I did not try. I broke my head with this - the whole last week. It has to be some function that has to loop the whole list every time and find out open/close accordions. Probably `for` but at this moment my competencies are insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one would usually use a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext). The context can then manage the current accordion (or a key representing it) or dispatch events to other accordion instances.

As an example of storing the current accordion:

```js
import { setContext, getContext } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const key = {}; // Object instances are unique, hence useful for keys

export const getAccordionContext = () => getContext(key);
export const createAccordionContext = () => {
    const current = writable(null);
    const context = { current };
    setContext(key, context);
    
    return context;
}
```

If there is no wrapper component that is used in conjunction with the accordion items, a context has be created elsewhere (e.g. the `App`). Also, each accordion item should also create its own context, so if it contains items of its own, it will not be closed if a child is opened.

When an accordion is opened the current accordion of the context can be updated. A reactive statement can be used to close all other accordions that belong to a context.

```js
// In Accordion.svelte
const { current } = getAccordionContext();
const currentKey = {}; // Object representing current accordion component

createAccordionContext(); // Context for children

function handleClick() {
    open = !open
    if (open)
        $current = currentKey;
}

$: if ($current != currentKey)
    open = false;
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/29bf8248d5044e12877e9cbec9381115?version=3.48.0)