# How to edit the functionality of Accordion through the context in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, accordion, svelte

If you look at the example below, is it possible to set up the context (Svelte) in a way that some of the accordions (the first/second or third) will be open when the page is visited and then have standard functionality?

I am using this code as a list of questions for the help section similar to the FAQ.
When I refer from some page of my website to the help section I would like to redirect to the state where is accordion already open and visitors see the sub-menu of the accordion too.

At this moment it works in a way that every time when someone visits the help section all accordions are closed.

[Original previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778092/open-one-accordion-section-at-a-time-svelte/72778653#72778653)

A special shout-out to [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b)

App.svelte

```
<script>
import Accordion, { createAccordionContext } from 
"./Accordion.svelte"

createAccordionContext()
</script>

   <Accordion>
      <div slot="head">
          <h2>Test one</h2>
      </div>
      <div slot="details">
          <ul>
            <Accordion>
                <div slot="head">
                  <h4>The test of subitem?</h4>
                </div>
                <div slot="details">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </div>
            </Accordion >

            <Accordion>
                <div slot="head">
                    <h4>Test of subitem 2</h4>
                </div>
                <div slot="details">
                    <li>one</li>
                    <li>two</li>
                    <li>three</li>
                </div>
            </Accordion>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </Accordion>

   <Accordion>
      <div slot="head">
          <h4>Second test</h4>
      </div>
      <div slot="details">
          <ul>
              <li>again one</li>
              <li>two again</li>
              <li>three repeat</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </Accordion>


<style>
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

h4, h2 {
        cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Accordion.svelte

```
<script context=module>
import { setContext, getContext } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const key = {};

export const getAccordionContext = () => getContext(key);
export const createAccordionContext = () => {
    const current = writable(null);
    const context = { current };
    setContext(key, context);
    
    return context;
}
</script>
<script>
import { quadInOut } from 'svelte/easing';
import { slide } from 'svelte/transition';

export let open = false;

    const { current } = getAccordionContext();
    const currentKey = {};

    createAccordionContext(); // Context for children

function handleClick() {
    open = !open
            if (open)
                $current = currentKey;
}

    $: if ($current != currentKey)
        open = false;
</script>

<div  class="accordion">
  <div class="header" on:click={handleClick}>
      <div class="text">
          <slot name="head"></slot> 
      </div>
  </div>

  {#if open}
  <div class="details" transition:slide="{{ duration: 150, 
  easing:quadInOut }}" >
      <slot name="details">
      </slot>
  </div>
  {/if}

</div>

<style>
   div.accordion {
      margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  div.header {
      display:flex;
      width:100%;
  }
  div.header .text {
      flex: 1;
  }
  div.details {
      background-color: transparent;
      padding:1rem;
  }
</style>
```

Full [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/29bf8248d5044e12877e9cbec9381115?version=3.48.0)

Comment: By the way, one should not add click handlers on just any element. They belong on interactive elements like `button`. Otherwise the result will be less accessible (e.g. keyboard interactions will not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would split this into two components: `Accordion` and `AccordionItem`

`Accordion` manages the shared context and allows the configuration of the opened item. This also gets rid of having to call the context creation function at the top level.

The items contain most of the logic for showing/hiding content and all of the styling/layout.

Each item could export the key used to identify the item, then you can use e.g. numbers or strings to identify them and set the item to be opened on the `Accordion` wrapper.

E.g.

```html
<!-- Accordion -->
<script context=module>
    import { setContext, getContext } from 'svelte';
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
    const key = {};

    export const getAccordionContext = () => getContext(key);
    export const createAccordionContext = initial => {
        const current = writable(initial);
        const context = { current };
        setContext(key, context);
        
        return context;
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let current = null;
    
    const { current: currentStore } = createAccordionContext(current);

    // Synchronize property <-> context
    $: currentStore.set(current);
    $: current = $currentStore;
</script>

<slot />
```

```html
<!-- AccordionItem -->
<script>
    import { getAccordionContext } from './Accordion.svelte';
    // ...
    
    export let key = {};
    
    const { current } = getAccordionContext();
    
    function handleClick() {
        $current = open ? null : key;
    }
    
    $: open = $current == key;
</script>

<div class="accordion">
    ...
<div>
```

Then you can do something like:

```html
<Accordion current="a">
    <AccordionItem key="a">...</AccordionItem>
    <AccordionItem key="b">...</AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/760d33407acc43bf8013d9da015d7240?version=3.48.0)

If you have nested accordions, you might want to use `bind:current={...}` to save the state of accordions, as the `#if` used to show/hide the accordion item content will reset everything within on close.

You could also use indices instead of explicit keys. To do that you would make the elements register themselves in the context via a function, so each item can get a separate index. Though then you should also make sure they unregister via `onDestroy`.

Comment: What is this `$: current = $currentStore;` for inside `Accordion`?

Comment: It synchronizes the store (context for children) with the property. That is from context to property, the other reactive statement is for property to context.

Comment: Ah ok, get's clearer with the updated Repl... thanks!

Comment: This is a great solution. I tried to adjust a `key` property through a new function, but unsuccessfully. Now, after your reply, it is so obvious that the easiest way is to create two components and add the "selection part" separately to a new component. Thanks H.B. I'm learning a lot through your contributions.